# AWS Amplify returns generic Network Error for only on some android devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-lambda, general-network-error

I am using aws amplify to call apis, problem is for some android devices I am getting 'network error at create error' and the app is running somoothly on other devices.

I do not get any log in logs of lambda function that is being called. so i am not sure if the problem is from server side or amplify fails before connecting to server.

one more thing i am calling another api from different stack but same configration and it is being called successfully.

I have tried to updated the amplify version from 1.3.3 to 4.0.38 but still same error.

help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: even i am facing the same error
any solution

Thanks

Comment: @RanvijayKumarSingh I dont remember exactly but there was some option in api gateway configration which lead to show more specifict error, and for our case the error was related to date time of the mobile device. time of the mobile device was different than the actual time so that was causing issue for us.

Comment: Thanks , and i checked my Time and Date Setting, it is all Default and Still i am getting This Error. Please help.